# Trying to change the scale of a health bar using collider and it does not register

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the code for the Player game object  i am trying to damage a game object when it collides with another game object and transform the scale of a healthbar, extra text because i am receiving an error saying i am putting too much code and too little writing on my question so here we go i guess.

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 moveDirection;
    bool facingRight = true;
    public static float healthAmount;


    void Start()
    {        
        healthAmount = 1f;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2d(Collider2D col)
    {

        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Bat")           
                   healthAmount = -0.1f;
        

    }



    void Update()
    {
        ProcessInputs();

        if (healthAmount <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

    }

    // movement math
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Move();
    }

    void ProcessInputs()
    {
        float moveX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float moveY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        
        moveDirection = new Vector2(moveX, moveY).normalized;

        if (moveX < 0 && facingRight)
        {

            Flip();

        }
        else if (moveX > 0 && !facingRight)
        {

            Flip();
        }
    }

    void Move()
    {

        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveDirection.x * moveSpeed, moveDirection.y * moveSpeed);

    }

    void Flip()
    {

        facingRight = !facingRight;
        transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);

    }

}

and this is the code for the health bar

public class HealthBarS : MonoBehaviour
{

    Vector3 localScale;

    void Start()
    {
        localScale = transform.localScale;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        localScale.x = PlayerMovement.healthAmount;
        transform.localScale = localScale;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you specify the wrong behavior? Is is about collision not happening? Or maybe incorrect scaling? Did you try debugging or reading the docs on OnTriggerEnter2d?

Comment: the issue is that when the Bat enemy which has the Bat tag on it collides with the Player character the healthAmount does not get reduced.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you need the PlayerMovement instance, not the class. Also make sure the bat object's collider is marked as trigger. Try this:

```cs
public class HealthBarS : MonoBehaviour
{

    Vector3 localScale;
    PlayerMovement playerMovement;

    void Start()
    {
        playerMovement = FindObjectOfType<PlayerMovement>();
        localScale = transform.localScale;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        localScale.x = playerMovement.healthAmount;
        transform.localScale = localScale;
    }
}
```